# C#, value getting over-written instead of retaining old value and adding new

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to make it so that the value of total per is the sum of all the `employeePer*`, For example if there are two employees with `employeePer1= 2` and `employeePer2 = 2`, the total should be 4, entering the first two if statements. But instead totalPer is always assigned the value of the last `if` statement it went into e.g in the example above `totalper` would == 2 not 4,
Thanks for any help

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int numberOfEmps = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["employees"]);
    int totalPercent = 100*(Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["employees"]));
    Response.Write(totalPercent);
    int totalPer = 0;

    if(numberOfEmps == 1)
    {
    int employee1Per =  (Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["employee1Per"]));
    Response.Write(employee1Per);
    int employee1Att = (Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["employee1Att"]));
    int employee1Sal = (Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["employee1Sal"]));
    int employee1Yer = (Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["employee1Yer"]));
        totalPer += employee1Per;
    }
    if(numberOfEmps == 2)
    {
    int employee2Per = (Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["employee2Per"]));
    int employee2Att = (Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["employee2Att"]));
    int employee2Sal = (Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["employee2Sal"]));
    int employee2Yer = (Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["employee2Yer"]));
        totalPer +=  employee2Per;
    }
    if(numberOfEmps == 3)
    {
    int employee3Per = (Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["employee3Per"]));
    int employee3Att = (Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["employee3Att"]));
    int employee3Sal = (Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["employee3Sal"]));
    int employee3Yer = (Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["employee3Yer"]));
        totalPer +=employee3Per;
    }
    if(numberOfEmps == 4)
    {
    int employee4Per = (Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["employee4Per"]));
    int employee4Att = (Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["employee4Att"]));
    int employee4Sal = (Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["employee4Sal"]));
    int employee4Yer = (Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["employee4Yer"]));
        totalPer +=employee4Per;
    }
    if(numberOfEmps == 5)
    {
    int employee5Per = (Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["employee5Per"]));
    int employee5Att = (Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["employee5Att"]));
    int employee5Sal = (Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["employee5Sal"]));
    int employee5Yer = (Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["employee5Yer"]));
        totalPer +=employee5Per;
    }
    if(numberOfEmps == 6)
    {
    int employee6Per = (Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["employee6Per"]));
    int employee6Att = (Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["employee6Att"]));
    int employee6Sal = (Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["employee6Sal"]));
    int employee6Yer = (Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["employee6Yer"]));
        totalPer +=employee6Per;
    }
    if(numberOfEmps == 7)
    {
    int employee7Per = (Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["employee7Per"]));
    int employee7Att = (Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["employee7Att"]));
    int employee7Sal = (Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["employee7Sal"]));
    int employee7Yer = (Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["employee7Yer"]));
        totalPer +=employee7Per;
    }
    if(numberOfEmps == 8)
    {
    int employee8Per = (Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["employee8Per"]));
    int employee8Att = (Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["employee8Att"]));
    int employee8Sal = (Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["employee8Sal"]));
    int employee8Yer = (Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["employee8Yer"]));
        totalPer +=employee8Per;
    }
    if(numberOfEmps == 9)
    {
    int employee9Per = (Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["employee9Per"]));
    int employee9Att = (Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["employee9Att"]));
    int employee9Sal = (Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["employee9Sal"]));
    int employee9Yer = (Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["employee9Yer"]));
        totalPer +=employee9Per;
    }
    if(numberOfEmps == 10)
    {
    int employee10Per = (Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["employee10Per"]));
    int employee10Att = (Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["employee10Att"]));
    int employee10Sal = (Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["employee10Sal"]));
    int employee10Yer = (Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["employee10Yer"]));
        totalPer +=employee10Per;
    }
    if(numberOfEmps == 11)
    {
    int employee11Per = (Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["employee11Per"]));
    int employee11Att = (Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["employee11Att"]));
    int employee11Sal = (Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["employee11Sal"]));
    int employee11Yer = (Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["employee11Yer"]));
        totalPer +=employee11Per;
    }
    if(numberOfEmps == 12)
    {
    int employee12Per = (Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["employee12Per"]));
    int employee12Att = (Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["employee12Att"]));
    int employee12Sal = (Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["employee12Sal"]));
    int employee12Yer = (Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["employee12Yer"]));
        totalPer +=employee12Per;
    }

    Label7.Text = (totalPer.ToString());
    Label9.Text = (totalPercent.ToString());

}
```

Comment: I dont understand, what kind of code is this... you are having if conditions so many times? What if `Request.QueryString["employees"]` return value greater than 12 in future?????

Comment: Shouldn't your if statements use `<=` instead of `==` ? As it's written, only one block above will be executed. If `numberOfEmps` is 2, only the second conditional runs. With a change to `<=`, the first two conditionals will run.

Comment: Ya thanks Rick, Jesus, what a stupid mistake

Comment: @RickLiddle: You are on the right way, it's the operator that is wrong. However `numberOfEmps <= 1` is still `false` if `numberOfEmps` is `2`.

Comment: You have a load of unused variables, and code that could be refactored into a function. Clean code is always easier to debug. Also putting breakpoint and stepping through the code is the first option.

Comment: @Guffa You're right. I think I need more coffee.

Comment: Once your code is working, I recommend posting it on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ .  There are better ways to accomplish this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If there are two employees, the code won't enter the first two `if` statemenets, it will only enter the second.

For the first `if` statement you would want to check if there are one employee or more, not exactly one employee:

```
if(numberOfEmps >= 1)
```

Then the corresponding for all the other `if` statements.

Comment: Also I would use a for loop with string.Format. This would have avoided the problem from the begining

Answer (score 1):

There's **a lot** of refactoring you could do here, and although this question has been answered correctly I felt you might benefit from another perspective to achieve what you're trying to do.

First, I'd have some kind of structure to store my employees in, so let's use a `struct` for example:

```
struct Employee
{
    int Per;
    int Att;
    int Sal;
    int Yer;
}
```

Now, because the number of employees is a variable, what you have doesn't scale past 12 so I'd `for` through to the number given and create instances of `Employee` from the `QueryString` data and store them in some kind of collection `List<T>` for now, something like this:

```
List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();    
int numberOfEmps = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["employees"]);
for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfEmps; i++)
{
    Employee employee = new Employee()
    {
        Per =  Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString[string.Format("employee{0}Per", i)]),
        Att = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString[string.Format("employee{0}Att", i)]),
        Sal = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString[string.Format("employee{0}Sal", i)]),
        Yer = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString[string.Format("employee{0}Yer", i)])
    };
    employees.Add(employee);
}
```

Then you have 2 options of counting up your `Per` properties, you could use an iterator:

```
int totalPer = 0;
foreach (var employee in employees)
{
    totalPer = totalPer + employee.Per;
}
```

Or you could use `LINQ`:

```
totalPer = employees.Sum(e => e.Per);
```

Comment: +1 for taking the time to go beyond just fixing the bug and teach some refactoring

Answer (score 0):

You could make this a whole lot simpler using iteration as it appears you aren't doing much 
with employee[x]Per, employee[x]Att and employee[x]Sal

Something like:

```
int numberOfEmps = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["employees"]);
int totalPercent = 100*(Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["employees"]));
Response.Write(totalPercent);
int totalPer = 0;

for(int i = 1; i <= numberOfEmps; i++)
{
   int employeePer = (Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["employee" + i + "Per"]));
   totalPer +=employeePer;
}
```